# How to submit an operation not related to data processing to a Spark Cluster so that it will be executed on every nodes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've got a big Spark DataFrame loaded from list of files, from around 10K files. I want to do something with files (for example, copy them from one place to another). Currently I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor to do some tasks concurrently. I slice the list of files into chunks and process every chunks in parallel as follows:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
futures = []
for idx, files_chunk in enumerate(files_in_chunks):
    futures.append(executor.submit(process_chunk, chunk_index=idx, chunk_of_files=files_chunk))
concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)
```

The function `process_chunk` do the job I need.

But this, as I understand, forces to execute the logic only on one worker node, or even on master node. So that all parallel executions won't use all available worker nodes in the Spark Cluster.

How is it possible to submit `process_chunk` to Spark cluster, so that it can be executed on every available worker node, and, for example, use files from new RDD created from the list of files?

I'm using PySpark.

Comment: How you are exceuting the hob?Is it spark-shell or spark-submit?

Comment: It's utilizing GCP Dataproc cluster and I'm instantiating a workflow template created there. I'm not sure how exactly it submits a job under the hood. I thought it's not related to the way of submitting a job, but rather to the way, how it's declared in the code. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Check these properties https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties. Also the --jar will be added to the classpath and anything listed as a --file is available in each spark executor's working directory

Comment: @Subash I'm not sure I understand where you're directing my thoughts. On GCP cluster I can submit a PySpark job using this manual https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark But I don't see how this helps. Or maybe I don't know something. When I submit, I know that at first the master node execute the job and then submit some routines to Spark under the hood. So that when I write some like this: `df = dataFrame.filter(...)` in fact the work is shared between executor nodes and partitions and every piece is executed concurrently (we see stages).

Comment: What if I want to execute some function, having partition as an input dataset (a sub-dataset) to that function? How is it possible to declare in the Python code? For example, taking some list of files, we can create an RDD and then I want to copy every files. But I want the operation of copying to be executed using all nodes in Spark cluster. As I mentioned above, when I use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` it seems it executes on only one node, just in threads. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDD has such methods like:

- map
- mapPartitions
- mapPartitionsWithIndex

The function which they except will be executed on the cluster and can do any work you like. For example, copying of files.
It's also possible to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` inside the functions. It will improve performance as well.

To execute the function, need to call `.collect()` method after it. For example,

```
def process_chunks(idx, chunk_items):
  return [{"partition_idx":idx, "items": len(list(chunk_items))}]

items = range(1000)
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(items, numSlices=10)
result = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(process_chunks).collect()

print(result)
```

It will return:

```
[{'partition_idx': 0, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 1, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 2, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 3, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 4, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 5, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 6, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 7, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 8, 'items': 100}, {'partition_idx': 9, 'items': 100}]
```

You can read more here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations